# Getting: "java.nio.file.FileSystemException" when trying to move the file to a folder

Tags: java, database, file

This is my code, which accept generally .xlsx format file and insert to database and also move accept file to my specified folder. When I trying to move it, I have getting this error:

Normally, it successfully writes the received excel file to the database, but when I added the new feature, which move in specified folder, I started getting this error. I started using threads or something, but it didn't help.

```
 public static void acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase(File file) {

        try {
            String phoneNumber = "";
            String textMessage = "";
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);

            Path sourcePath = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
            Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\ko\\" + sourcePath.getFileName());

            Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath);

            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        phoneNumber = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                }

            }
            insertExcellFileToDb(phoneNumber, textMessage);
            System.out.println(phoneNumber + " " + textMessage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\anar.memmedov\Desktop\file.xlsx -> C:\Users\anar.memmedov\Desktop\ko\file.xlsx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at az.expressbank.insertdatabasetheexcellfile.util.ExcellWriteToDatabase.acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase(ExcellWriteToDatabase.java:37)
    at az.expressbank.insertdatabasetheexcellfile.test.Test.main(Test.java:29)
```

Comment: You are moving the file for which you have an open FileInputStream. While it may work, it would be better to do the move after `fis.close()` and `insertExcellFileToDb`, so that if the insert fails the file has not disappeared, or you could move file to errors directory instead. The value of sourcePath is simply `file.toPath()`.

Comment: @DuncG I already solved this problem, again thanks. One of the first things I do is open a file, apparently to read it. Then I try to move that file to a different folder. I cannot do that. If I open a file, I have to close it before I can move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing `FileInputStream` at the end.

Try to put this when you don't need the `fileInputStream`.

```
excelFile.close();
```

Comment: I have gettin same error, when using spring boot jpa, what do I am?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` with resource. It will automatically close your resource:

```
public static void acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase(File file) {

        try(FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            String phoneNumber = "";
            String textMessage = "";
           

            Path sourcePath = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
            Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\ko\\" + sourcePath.getFileName());

            Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath);

            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        phoneNumber = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                }

            }
            insertExcellFileToDb(phoneNumber, textMessage);
            System.out.println(phoneNumber + " " + textMessage);
        }
}
```